# Return conditional `range_expression`

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, constexpr, std-span

What's the most efficient way of iterating over one of several known ranges based on some condition?

pseudo-code for a binary condition:

```
for element in (condition ? range_a : range_b)
  // do work
```

This 'example' shows my intention using a [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) but as [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) has reference semantics it won't work.

```cpp
constexpr auto some_range(bool c) -> std::initializer_list<int> {
  if (c) {
    return {1,2};
  } else {
    return {3, 4, 5};
  }
}

bool cond = true; // false

for(auto x : some_range(cond)) {
  // things
}
```

*yields: `warning: returning address of local temporary object [-Wreturn-stack-address]`*

During run-time I could return a `std::vector` but that would involve constructing a new vector every call:

```cpp
auto some_range(bool c) -> std::vector<int> {
  if (c) {
    return {1,2};
  } else {
    return {3, 4, 5};
  }
}
```

I could use a fixed size `std::array` of `std::optional<int>` but I have to resort to a C++14 or c++11 solution.

Comment: Can you resort to a C++17 solution?

Comment: or `std::span` from c++20?

Comment: The ranges you intend to iterate over are definitely created from within `some_range`? Or would they exist in the scope of the calling code?

Comment: @Bathsheba @Jarod42 The code-base I am working on supports up to C++14. 
@lubgr Yes, that is my intention. I would like to encapsulate the data in the `some_range` function. In practice, `some_range` is a member function of a class that is responsible for providing the range.

Comment: Pity. Looks like a *constexpr if* type construction to me: and unlike some things out of later standards, you can't "borrow" the code from that later standard. Nice question though.

Comment: When are the values for the ranges known?  Are they, say, multiple member variables of the class in question?

Comment: @DavisHerring they're known from the function's context, when writing the function. So they could be stored as a member variable of a containing class. However I would rather 'hide' these values from the rest of the class by wrapping it in the function-to-be-written.

Comment: @Tom: Maybe I’m not following, but could they be static local variables?

Comment: @DavisHerring There are some costs involved in managing static variables https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B3WWsKFePiM, consequently, the compiler will not be able to optimize the range-based for loop. Check this demo with optimizer output: https://godbolt.org/z/v6RgFH

Comment: @Tom is [this](https://godbolt.org/z/uqo7sj) what you need ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Great suggestion... I ended up implementing an `array_view` that takes some `std::array<T,N>`... I've updated the Q to reflect this.

Comment: @Tom You're solution has the same pitfall as the original one, the `std::array` will not outlive `conditional_range()` so you'll have a view to an array that does not exists anymore.

Comment: Hold ur horses! @Holt The array now has static storage duration so it will exist, right?

Comment: @Tom In Piotr's solution yes, not in yours.

Comment: I see, you are right, thanks for warning!

Comment: It looks like you found what I meant by static locals, but it also looks like you’re supposed to have written an answer, not edited the question.

Comment: @DavisHerring Right you are, but there was the `view` involved to get it working correctly. Regarding the answer... I rather not hijack your efforts in finding a solution but allow anyone to provide a short answer instead.

Comment: It's still better to post your answer as an answer - you can still accept a different answer, and it leaves the question less cluttered.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A range-based for loop can iterate over any expression `e`, whose class type has `e.begin()` and `e.end()` member functions, or non-member functions `begin(e)` and `end(e)` can be found via ADL. A simple iterable view can be therefore:

```
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T>
struct view
{
    T* p;
    std::size_t s;
    constexpr T* begin() const { return p; }
    constexpr T* end() const { return p + s; }
};
```

and then returned holding a pointer to an array with, e.g., static storage duration:

```
inline view<const int> conditional_range(bool a)
{
    static int ra[] = { 1, 2 };
    static int rb[] = { 3, 4, 5 };
    if (a) return { ra, 2 };
    else return { rb, 3 };
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://godbolt.org/z/Scnx9w)

This is similar to what [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) offers with [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span).

---

An [`std::initilizer_list<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) wraps a local array, constructed automatically from the brace-enclosed initializer, and so is not usable as a return type, because in such a case the pointers it stores are invalidated on function exit.